# DevExpress ASPxCalendar Tooltip on Firefox

Tags: devexpress

In the DayRender function of DevExpress ASPxCalendar, I add a text for the tooltip of the date. The text contains newlines, and it works for Chrome and IE except Firefox. The code is like this:

```
protected void ASPxCalendar1_DayRender(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
...
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
strBuilder.Append("Some text");
strBuilder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
strBuilder.Append("Another text");
e.Day.Tooltip = strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240614/multiline-tooltip-via-asp-net-in-mozilla-firefox-is-it-possible thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this issue is caused by Firefox HTML processing specifics. Would you check whether it is possible to add the multiline ToolTip attribute to the standard HTML Table Cell ( tag) and display it in Firefox?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is as what you say, and multiline tooltip attribute in Firefox is a problem for now. I probably switch to another solution for this. 
Thanks